# How to create a Rent in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, system, store

I am tryng to develop a rent system where a user can login, create products, and his products can be rented by other users.

My problem is, I don't know how to create a rent that retrieves the `product_id` and `customer_id`. I made the relations but it isn't working.
I also create the CRUD for each one, even the rent. How can I store the information and pass to the Rent?

I have 4 models:

```
User
Product
Rent
Category
```

I created a new column in Rent called `customer_id`, and I've passed the class "User":

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :rents

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products
has_many :rents
has_many :customer_id, :through => :rent

class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :customer, :class_name => "User"
end
```

I think I need to create a button that retrieves the information that I need. I searched through the documentation but I couldn't find it.

Comment: When generating your rent model it may be best to use `rails generate model Rent product:references` since product already references user I wouldn't think that rent needs to. And as far as your user model goes are you trying to say that a user has many customers? Or is user the customer?

Comment: User will be the ownerd of the product, and another User will be the customer, with this i can create two panels, one for the owner and another for the customer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line: `has_many :customer_id, :through => :rent` would never make sense this way in Rails. If you say `has_many :customer_id`, you are making two mistakes:

1. Whatever you write after `has_many`, it should be plural.
2. If what you write after `has_many` doesn't correspond directly to a model name as this the case with you, you have to explicit mention the `class_name`.

Same mistake you are repeating when you say:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rents # it should be rent.
end
```

And now coming to what you are actually trying to implement:

```
class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :product
  has_one :customer
end
```

And in `Product` and `Customer` tables, you need to define `rent_id` as a foreign key. And you should also mention that each of them `belongs_to` `Rent`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!